# Is wp_enqueue_script required for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, security

Hi I'm a newbie at formats, and was wondering if we always have to use wp_enqueue_script() for javascript for wordpress.

Can we get away with   instead? thanks

Comment: It's not absolutely necessary as you can place scripts directly in the header or footer but it definitely is the heavily recommended method to use.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script()` FTW!

Comment: cool thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WordPress to accurately and properly add scripts and handle them appropriately, you should utilize the wp_enqueue_script() function. Otherwise, it may not load at all or improperly and cause conflicts in other areas.

Answer (score 0):

As others say, this is **hightly recommended**.

Here you can find more information and explaination about this function :

[Adding Scripts and Styles to WordPress the Right Way With Enqueueing - WPMU Dev](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-scripts-and-styles-wordpress-enqueueing/)

And finally the WordPress codex :

[WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts])